# prove that there is not a homeomorphic between $E$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Prove that $X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: ((x-2)^2+y^2-1)\cdot(x^2+y^2-1)=0 \}$
has a universal cover $(E,p)$ and prove that $E$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

$X$ is a bouquet of two circles and It's connected,locally path-connected and semi-locally simply connected thus $E$ is the universal cover and simply connected. Can I prove that $E$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Do you know how to build $E$? Do you know the fundamental group of $X$? Do you know what the Cayley graph is?

Comment: $E$ has trivial fundamental group. I think that the fundamental group of $X$ is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I don't know to build $E$ Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Cayley_graph_of_F2.svg That is $E$.